# How to use nested lists in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to attach 3 security groups to the EC2 instance. One which is creating in the template and the other two is existing where I am using mapping. I am getting an error when I use like this.

```
Mappings:
  envMap: 
    qa:
      "securityGroups":
        - sg-xxxxxxxx
        - sg-yyyyyyyy
```

Here is the resources I am creating....

```
Resources:
     InstanceSecurityGroup:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties:
        GroupDescription: Allow http to client host
        SecurityGroupIngress:
          - IpProtocol: tcp
            FromPort: 80
            ToPort: 80
            CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

        EC2Instance:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
      Properties:
        ImageId: !FindInMap [ envMap, !Ref env, ImageID ]
        InstanceType:
          !Ref 'InstanceSize'
        KeyName: !FindInMap [ envMap, !Ref env, KeyPairName ]
        SecurityGroupIds: [!Ref 'InstanceSecurityGroup',!FindInMap [ envMap, !Ref env, securityGroups ] ]
        SubnetId: !FindInMap [ envMap, !Ref env, Subnets ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't like inserting a list (returned from the Mapping) into a the `SecurityGroupsIds` list. That would put a list within a list.

If your intention is to always include certain security groups, and you are hard-coding the value of those security groups, then you could possibly use:

```
    SecurityGroupIds: [!Ref 'InstanceSecurityGroup','sg-xxxxxxxx', 'sg-yyyyyyyy' ] ]
```

I didn't test that syntax, so please try it to see if it works.

To make it a bit cleaner, you could specify those security groups as default values in Parameters and insert them from there.

Comment: This works but the security groups I want to use differs by each environment.

Comment: You might need to use a `!If` to switch between possible lines, instead of a mapping. Or, you could use two mappings, where each returns one security group, and refer to each mapping separately within the `SecurityGroupIds` list.

Comment: can you please share an example.

Comment: Use `SecurityGroupIds: [!Ref 'InstanceSecurityGroup', !FindInMap [ envMap1, !Ref env, securityGroups ], !FindInMap [ envMap2, !Ref env, securityGroups ]] ]` -- using two mappings so the values are returned individually rather than as a list. Put one value per region in each mapping.